# Express: I cant get Passport to authenticate the Login. Register is working but can you help passport Login Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport-local

I'm able to allow users to register an email and password.  The login allows any user to bypass authentication with no credentials at all. They just have to push the login button and they're in. Thank you!

> **LoginController.js**

```
    myApp.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'DataFactory', function($scope, DataFactory){

      $scope.dataFactory = DataFactory;

      $scope.failedLogin = false;

      $scope.loginUser = function() {

        var user = {
          email: $scope.email,
          password: $scope.password
        };

        $scope.failedLogin = false;

        $scope.dataFactory.factoryLoginUser(user);
      };
    }]);
```

> **Encryption.js module**

```
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

    var publicAPI = {
      encryptPassword: function(password) {
        var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(SALT_WORK_FACTOR);
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
      },
      comparePassword: function(candidatePassword, storedPassword) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, storedPassword);
      }
    };

    module.exports = publicAPI;
```

> **dataFactory.js**

```
myApp.factory('DataFactory', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {
  var apiData = undefined;
  var apiPhotoData = undefined;
  var isUserLoggedIn = false;
  var displayReminderMessage = false;

  // Private




  var privateAddNewUser = function(user) {
    $http.post('/register', user).then(function(response){
      console.log('Successfully added new user');
    });
  };

  var privateLoginUser = function(user) {
    console.log('sending login to server');
    $http.post('/login', user).then(

      function (res) {
        $location.path('/search');
        isUserLoggedIn = true;
      },
      function (err) {
        $location.path('/failure');
      });
  };



      factoryAddNewUser: function(user) {
        return privateAddNewUser(user);
      },
      factoryLoginUser: function(user) {
        return privateLoginUser(user);
      },


  };

    return publicAPI;

}]);
```

> **UserStrategy.js**

```
var passport = require('passport'); var localStrategy =
> require('passport-local').Strategy; var encryptLib =
> require('../modules/encryption'); var connectionString =
> require('../modules/connection'); var pg = require('pg');
> 
> passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {   console.log('hola');  
> done(null, user.id); });
> 
> passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
> 
>   pg.connect(connectionString, function (err, client) {
> 
>     var user = {};
>     console.log('called deserializeUser - pg');
>     var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1", [id]);
> 
>     query.on('row', function (row) {
>       console.log('User row', row);
>       user = row;
>       done(null, user);
>     });
> 
>     // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
>     query.on('end', function () {
>       client.end();
>     });
> 
>     // Handle Errors
>     if (err) {
>       console.log(err);
>     }   }); });
> 
> // Does actual work of logging in passport.use('local', new
> localStrategy({   passReqToCallback: true,   usernameField: 'email'  
> }, function(req, email, password, done){
>     pg.connect(connectionString, function (err, client) {
>       console.log('called local - pg');
>       var user = {};
>       var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [email]);
> 
>       //user = query;
>       //
>       //console.log('user is: ', user);
> 
>       query.on('row', function (row) {
>         console.log('User obj', row);
>         user = row;
> 
>         // Hash and compare
>         if (encryptLib.comparePassword(password, user.password)) {
>           // all good!
>           console.log('matched');
>           done(null, user);
>         } else {
>           console.log('nope');
>           done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect credentials.'});
>         }
> 
>       });
> 
>       // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
>       query.on('end', function () {
>         console.log('ending the stuff');
>         client.end();
>       });
> 
>       // Handle Errors
>       if (err) {
>         //console.log('yup');
>         console.log(err);
>       }
>     });   } ));
> 
> module.exports = passport;
```

> **LogInRoute.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('../strategies/user.js');

// Handles login form POST from index.html
router.post('/',
    passport.authenticate('local', {

        successRedirect: '/views/templates/search.html',
        failureRedirect: '/views/templates/login.html'
    })
);

module.exports = router;
```

> **app.js Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pg = require('pg');
var passport = require('./strategies/user.js');
var session = require('express-session');
var register = require('./routes/register');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var ZWSID = "X1-ZWz19ssev2coi3_1u0pu";
var Zillow = require('node-zillow');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Passport Session Configuration //
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  key: 'user',
  resave: 'true',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {maxage: 60000, secure: false}
}));

// start up passport sessions
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/register', register);
app.use('/login', login);


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('public/views'));
app.use(express.static('public/templates'));
app.use(express.static('public/fonts'));
app.use(express.static('public/images'));
app.use(express.static('public/scripts'));
app.use(express.static('public/scripts/factories'));
app.use(express.static('public/scripts/controllers'));
app.use(express.static('public/styles'));
app.use(express.static('public/styles/css'));
app.use(express.static('public/styles/scss'));
app.use(express.static('public/vendors'));


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
});
```

Comment: What's your question? Also this is way too much code to handle. Try writing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of your question.

Answer (score 0):

*> I figured it out.*

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport'); // ../strategies/user.js


    router.post('/',
      passport.authenticate('local'),
      function (req, res) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      });

    module.exports = router;
```